# Create OpenVPN/easy-rsa certificate from public key only

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, openvpn

I have been using easyrsa to generate client certificates for my application using the method [described here](http://www.hydrogen18.com/blog/your-own-pki-tls-golang.html).

The `build-client-full` command generates a fresh private key for each client. This is what I currently use... run `build-client-full` send the private key, certificate and ca cert to the client.

What I want to do is have the client generate their own private key locally, send me their public key, and I make the certificate and send it to the client where me as the CA decides the properties of the cert (Common name specifically).

How do I go about it? If I have the client generate CSR, how do I edit the properties in easyrsa before signing? Is easyrsa too simple for this and I need something more complex?

Answer (score 1):

You can use import-req command to import client csr and then sign it. For more info check the [documentation](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/tree/master/doc) of easy-rsa program

Comment: Yes, but how would I edit the csr before(or after) doing import-req?

Comment: If the request is done by rules you do not need to edit it by hand. If users want to create request by self should follow the rules

Comment: Screw the rules. I want to decide what goes into the cert. Only thing I want from the user is public key. I dont want to tell the user "hey make csr with these paramaters and send it to me". I want to tell them "send me your public key and I give you cert to use".

Comment: In such case you can create web form where they will fill and enter info and you will set the rest of the info